# My machine is not booting properly. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: 10.04, boot, boot-failure

I have a Lenovo x120e that is not booting properly.  When I turn it on, it just opens to a blank screen.

The machine is running Ubuntu 10.04.

**Main Details:**
I shut the lid of the computer while it was running, and then opened it later and noticed that I couldn't get out of suspend / hibernate mode.  I subsequently powered it down by holding the power button.  Now when I turn it back on, it just opens to a blank black screen, as if it is still in suspend / hibernate.

**Other Details:** The 10.04 operating system (A) was installed while this HD was in another laptop.  Since I moved the HD into this machine, I have been booting another OS (B), and never updated drivers in A to work with this machine.  (Does this matter for this particular situation / problem?)

**What I have tried so far:**
I found the REISUB method [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) but I don't have a SysReq button.

**What are my next steps to troubleshoot / solve?**

Comment: [Reposted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/how-do-i-troubleshoot-this-boot-issue). Please [don't do that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting); in the future, ask for a moderator to migrate your question if you want to move it to a different site.

Answer (score 1):

Now this may seem very stupid and very, very nooblike....And I'm afraid I'll be downgraded till no reputation is left.
But when my laptop has issues like that i.e. booting to blank screen it often helps to take out the battery, disconnect the plug and hold the power button for a couple of seconds.